# Retrieve Google Auth tokens from Okta sign-in?

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, google-signin, okta

I have an application that relies on access to Google Calendar.  And, until now, I have authed through a "Sign in with Google" option, requesting the needed Calendar scopes.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** I would like allow Okta customers the ability to authenticate (mostly so I can support the SCIM management).  The trouble is I am not clear on how to retrieve the needed Google auth credentials to access the Google Calendar API.

**Where I'm at, so far:**
In my own Okta instance, I have successfully configured Google as an IDP, as well as an Okta app (tile), and can authenticate (OIDC) into Okta with my Google credentials, from my Node app.  However, the returned `external_id`, `access_token`, and `refresh_token` are all relevant to Okta, not Google.

**The Question:**
Is there a way to get the needed Google authorization elements, both `access_token` and `refresh_token`, from my handshake with Okta?

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern you need is to use [embedded tokens](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/#embedding-a-token), where the Google access token is embedded as a custom claim inside the Okta access token. By doing so, the authenticated user can access both their application resources and also their own Google resources.

Unfortunately most providers don't suoport this, though it is a commonly desired extensibility feature. For Okta I would take a look at the [custom claims handling](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-tokens-returned-from-okta/main/) and in particular the [Okta Expression Language](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/okta-expression-language/). Hopefully you can get the Google access token as an attribute of the Idp User Profile, eg named `access_token`, though I don't know for sure if it will work.

Comment: Apparently, Okta _does_ provide a way to get the Access Token via their Social Auth (https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/idps/#social-authentication-token-operation).  However, you don't get back the Refresh Token.  And for Google, I don't know of a way to query for that outside of the OAuth handshake (with "offline" and "consent").  Any further thoughts?

Comment: If you get a 401 when calling a Google API, redirect the user to sign in again, then redirect the user back to the same place in the app and retry the API call. This needs coding in any OAith secured app. You may be able to configure Google token times to limit the frequency of having to do this.

Comment: This works if you are authenticating directly through the Google OAuth API (though you need to re-auth about every 4 hours, as you still don't get a Refresh Token on subsequent log-ins, which is less than ideal).  However, Okta's Social Auth _does not fetch a new Access Token_, unless you end your Okta session (sign out of Okta).  In fact, if you use the Okta Social Auth one day, and try it the next day it will fail b/c your Okta session will still be live but your Google session (through Okta) has expired.  The only way to fix this is to log out of Okta, and try again.

Comment: I'm aware that some of my trouble here may be in my approach.  However, with all the large companies that use Okta for User/Access-management, I find it odd that there isn't more documentation on how to this subject.  I want to use Okta as the Authenticator (if not the IDP) but rely on Google or MS as the calendar service (with which Okta should already be integrated).  Ideally, this would occur without asking the user to log in twice.  Or remove Okta as a superfluous piece.  If I'm being naive, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Ideally you should be able to either get the Google refresh token, (preferred) or configure a longer Google access token expiry. It is tricky though, since Google access tokens can't be used to protect your own data, and Okta access tokens cannot be used to access Google resources. The pattern I suggest is correct, but seems like Okta don't allow you to get the Google refresh token.